# master..xp_cmdshell is blockes on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, windows

**How to enable the
   `xp_cmdshell` and why is it blocked or disabled?***

Comment: most DBA's who know what they are doing won't enable xp_cmdshell; and in fact it is likely to be deprecated!

Comment: What is it you want to use it for? There are usually safer alternatives

Comment: Sir i want to run a .exe file with in a trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while enabling  you need  Check out the Permission section of the

> xp_cmdshell MSDN docs:
>   please follow link

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190693.aspx




    EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
    GO

    RECONFIGURE
    GO

    EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
    GO

    RECONFIGURE
    GO
```

Comment: 1. Try not to copy content. 2. (if you do 1)You should explicitly state the source from which you have copied the content.

Comment: yeah starting itself i posted xp_cmdshell MSDN docs: ...@TheLostMind

Comment: @Chanukya: see [how to reference materials](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing); what is missing is a link.

Answer (score 0):

xp_cmdshell- Executes a given command string or batch file as an operating-system command shell and returns any output as rows of text.

***Permission/Rights:*** Only SysAdmin fixed role can execute it.

Syntax

xp_cmdshell {‘command_string‘} [, no_output]
Arguments

‘command_string‘

Is the command string to execute at the operating-system command shell or from DOS prompt. command_string is varchar(255) or nvarchar(4000), with no default.

command_string cannot contain more than one set of double quotation marks.

A single pair of quotation marks is necessary if any spaces are present in the file paths or program names referenced by command_string.

If you have trouble with embedded spaces, consider using FAT 8.3 file names as a workaround.

no_output

Is an optional parameter executi

-- To allow advanced options to be changed.
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE
GO
-- Disable xp_cmdshell option now
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

FOr More Info-- http://yrushka.com/index.php/sql-server/security/execute-remotely-t-sql-command-through-xp_cmdshell/

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Master
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```